# What is risky about the following and how could you rewrite it to make it safer?

Tags: c#

how would you answer this interview question?

What is risky about the following and how could you rewrite it to make it safer?

`class Line
{public Point  p1; public Point  p2; public double length;}`

Thanks,

Comment: Since OP is a new user, provide some help for the question rather than closing. I think for a beginner, it is a good question as to why we would use property getter/setters and the optional use of backing fields.

Comment: @IAbstract You are of course free to do so if you would like.  Why did you choose not to?

Comment: @Servy: I didn't downvote the question. :) Several have downvoted and not given a reason for doing so. Since the OP is new, it would be helpful to provide tips or editing that improve the question.

Comment: @IAbstract Voting is designed to be anonymous.  Note that this question a) doens't show research effort, or any effort at all on the side of the OP to attempt to solve the problem; it's just a verbatim copy of a question he saw elsewhere.  What was his answer?  What concerns did he have with it?  What did the interviewer say in response?  On top of that, the question is highly subjective.  It's not asking for facts, and as such is "not constructive" and isn't appropriate for the site to begin with. I see no refactor to this question to get around that; the question is to fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @IAbstract, Thanks for your support. Servy you are right I should explain the concerns I had. Thanks to Cyborgx37 he explained it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First off, you haven't set an explicit modifier on the class, so your are going to end up with whatever the default happens to be (if it's in the namespace then `internal` or `private` if contained in a class). This can cause minor inconveniences at compile-time. A bigger issue might be if the default exposes the class beyond what was intended, in which case you may unwittingly allowing greater access to the class than what was expected. In any case, it's difficult for beginner or moderate C# programmers to glance at this and know what to expect, which can be a maintainability issue.
2. The biggest issue, though, is that all of your class fields are declared public. Typically you'd want to use properties to expose fields: to restrict read/write ability, to make the fields more discoverable via reflection, to perform validation, etc. Which leads to...
3. You can see that the class is named "Line" and exposes both it's points and it's length. A caller can currently easily change any of those values, but the other values are not updated. Length should probably be calculated property (read-only) given that changing the length would have unpredictable results (which point would change?).

   So I would rewrite this class as:

   ```
   public class Line
   {
       public Point P1 {get;set;}
       public Point P2 {get;set;}
       public double Length
       {
           get
           {
               return Math.Sqrt( 
                   Math.Pow( P2.X - P1.X, 2 ) + 
                   Math.Pow( P2.Y - P1.Y, 2 ) 
               );
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. The mutability of this class can cause issues if there are multiple threads working together, or even in a simple case where two objects are referencing the same Line instance and one object might not aware of another's changes (thus causing problems). If mutability is an issue, then all of the properties should be read-only:

   ```
   public class Line
   {
       private Point _p1;
       public Point P1
       {
           get
           {
               return _p1;
           }
       }
       private Point _p2;
       public Point P2
       {
           get
           {
               return _p2;
           }
       }
       private double _length;
       public double Length
       {
           get
           {
               return _length;
           }
       }

       public Line(Point p1, Point p2)
       {
           _p1 = p1;
           _p2 = p2;
           _length = Math.Sqrt( 
                   Math.Pow( _p2.X - _p1.X, 2 ) + 
                   Math.Pow( _p2.Y - _p1.Y, 2 ) 
               );
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: @Cyborgx37, Thanks perfect explanations

Answer (score 3):

If the intention was for the length member to provide the length of the line, then the risk is that the length can be changed with no regard to the 'real' distance between the points.

There are many ways to address this. Here is one:

```
class Line {
  public Point p1;
  public Point p2;
  public double length {
     get {
        return ....
     }
  }
}
```

This way the distance is calculated every time it is accessed and it is read - only and as such protected from changes introducing inconsistency

Comment: Depending upon the intended usage of `Line`, this may be the right approach.  Hiding `p1` and `p2` behind properties will make it more difficult to do things like move one end of the line horizontally or vertically, but could allow the `Line` to notify something when its endpoints are moved.  My inclination would either be to have `Line` be a struct with exposed fields, or a class with properties (again depending upon usage).

Answer (score 1):

All of the members should be property getter/setters. The backing members/fields would be optional.
The exception is the Length property. You do not want Length modified independent of the Line characteristics - e.g. without consideration of the point coordinates making the property read-only.

```
class Line {
   private Point _startPoint;
   private Point _endPoint;

   public double Length {
      get { return _startPoint.X - _endPoint.X; } // modify for your own algorithm
   }

   // add public property setters for Start and End Points
}
```

This prevents an end-developer or consuming app from modifying the length independent of the line coordinates.

Note:
A line seems to be a value type and could be a struct.